# Redshift order of sory keys vs table creation column order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have table in Redshift as with columns ‘a1_timestamp, a2_cd, a3_id,a4,a5’ (in that order).   I want to create sort key on columns ‘a3_id and a1_timestamp’.

Since table is created with a1_timestamp as 1st column and a3_id as 3rd columns, do sort key need to be in that order? These are compound sort keys.

Answer (score 0):

Column order doesn't affect sort keys. You can create a sort key [altering the table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html).

> When data is loaded into a table, the data is loaded in the order of the sort key. When you alter the sort key, Amazon Redshift reorders the data

But that won't reorder the columns.